# Multiple AWS Lambda functions using the same libraries

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am writing AWS Lambda functions for my android app backend. I have multiple Lambda functions in python on AWS which requires the same libraries. For example, I need to access the database so I use pymysql library in all my lambda functions. But I am not sure whether I am doing it right.

Do I have to include these libraries in every function package that I deploy or is there a better way by which I can reference the libraries I have used in the previous function?

I am following [Tutorial: Accessing Amazon RDS in an Amazon VPC](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc-rds-deployment-pkg.html). I have 2 functions. I am uploading each function separately with its dependencies in a zip. Zip contains the code and libraries. Libraries takes most of the space making zip size big. Now the second function also requires the same libraries so again making a zip with same libraries feels wrong.

Also some links to where this is mentioned in docs is helpful. I did not find it anywhere in documentation.

Comment: You have to include the libraries in each Lambda function you deploy. There is no mechanism for sharing them between functions.

Comment: @MarkB Wont that simply make my functions bulky? My library takes around 5mb and i have around 20 functions using the same library

Comment: Or is there any way by which i can club multiple functions together in a zip and upload them

Comment: It doesn't "simply make your functions bulky". It also makes them independent. Each function has to run in a container completely separated from the other functions, so each function has to include all dependencies.

Answer (score 4):

You can share your code using [AWS Lambda Layers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html). For example define them using `AWS::Lambda::LayerVersion` or `AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion`. You can then reference to them in your Python Lambda functions.
Here using [AWS SAM](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model) :

```
  MyLambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: function_code/
      Handler: app.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.6
      Layers:
        - !Ref MySharedLayer
  MySharedLayer:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion
    Properties:
      LayerName: SharedLayerName
      Description: Some shared code
      ContentUri: layer_code/
      CompatibleRuntimes:
        - python3.6
      RetentionPolicy: Retain
```

Each Lambda function will have the shared code available in `/opt`. It can be then used in the functions.

Answer (score 0):

Now that the [Lambda Layers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html#configuration-layers-path) are released you can easily share libraries and code between your Lambda Functions.

You can create a zip file for the Layer pretty much the same way as you can do so for a Function.
To share `pymysql` package you will need to create a Lambda Layer on base of the following function:

```
pymysql-bundle.zip/
  python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql
```

Then from your Lambda Function's code you can reference it like this:

```
from pymysql import ...
```