# AWS API Gateway, use unified Python file for Lambdas

Tags: python, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am building my first REST API using API Gateway. I intend to use Python Lambda functions to do the work. I'm seeing that each Lambda function comes with its own space in which to insert Python code, but to me it would make a lot better sense to have one Python file containing all my handlers. I see that Lambda allows us to choose the name of the handler for the Lambda function, so that would seem to be workable. Is there some way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can organize your Lambda functions in a single Python file and have multiple handlers within that file.

Sample (api_handlers.py):

```
import json

def handler1(event, context):
  print("handler1")
  pass
 
def handler2(event, context):
  print("handler2")
  pass

def lambda_handler(event, context):
  if event['EventType'] == 'handler1':
    handler1(event, context)
  elif event['EventType'] == 'handler2':
    handler2(event, context)
```

Test-case for handler1, Event Json:

```
{
  "EventType": "handler1"
}
```

[image]

Test-case for handler2, Event Json:

```
{
  "EventType": "handler2"
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Omer, but there is a piece I'm missing. What do I do instead of just entering code in the "code source" area for each separate lambda function? How do I tell it that all these different lambdas are actually using the same code file?

Comment: Please have a look at Lambda Layers: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/chapter-layers.html. This will enable to use of shared files and libraries between different Lambda functions. Each Lambda function will have the shared code available in /opt. It can be then used in the functions (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45258995/multiple-aws-lambda-functions-using-the-same-libraries, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62371698/can-an-aws-lambda-function-call-another-normal-python-function-from-a-python-fil)